# Find the number of inequivalent two-dimensional complex representations of the group $Z_4$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Find the number of inequivalent two-dimensional complex representations of the group $Z_4$

Any hints will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all

Comment: Do you know what the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using Maschke's Theorem, any such two-dimensional representation of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is the direct sum of irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_4$. You need to find the irreducible representations of the group (which all turn out to be one-dimensional because the group is abelian). Thus, any two-dimensional representation is the sum of two of these irreducible representations. The question then becomes a combinatorial one: how many ways can you choose two irreducible representations?

Comment: Why does no one like abelian plays?  Because the characters are all one-dimensional! (laughter ensues)

Comment: Very nice pun, +1!

Comment: @TimRatigan Even though all the characters are one-dimensional, they can sometimes be complex!